# Prove that $A$ is open if and only if $A=\operatorname{int}{A}$

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, proof-explanation

I am quite confused by this statement, let me first post few definition that the paper I am reading, uses.

> **Definition:** Neighborhood of a set $A$ of topological space $\mathcal{X}$ is arbitrary open set containing $A$ (Eventually, if $A$ is open, it *can* be a neighbourhood of itself). Neighborhood of point $x\in \mathcal{X}$ is the neighborhood of set $\{x\}$.
>
> **Definition**: Assume topological space $\mathcal{X}$ and arbitrary set $A\subseteq \mathcal{X}$. A point $x\in \mathcal{X}$ satisfies one of the following:
>
> \begin{align*}
> \text{There exists a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ s.t. $U\subseteq A$}\tag{1}\\
> \text{There exists a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ s.t. $U\subseteq (\mathcal{X}\setminus A)$}\tag{2}
> \end{align*}
> The set of all points (1), (2) respectively we denote $\operatorname{int}{A},\operatorname{ext}{A}$ and call interior, exterior of a set $A$ respectively.

Now for the theorem:

> **Theorem**: $A$ is open if and oly if $A=\operatorname{int}{A}$.

The paper proposes the proof is very obvious, but I was trying to make sense of it. Basically it seems circular to me because whether a set is open or not depends on the actual *choice* of topology on $X$. Basically what I am trying to show is that $A$ is open if and only if for each point $x$ there is neighbourhood $U_x$ of $x$ s.t. $U_x\subseteq A$. So now:

*Proof*.
In any case $\operatorname{int}{A}\subseteq A$ is by definition.

$\Rightarrow:$ Assume $A$ is open. Take arbitrary point $x\in A$, choose $A$ as neighborhood of $x$, this means $x\in \operatorname{int}A$. This proves $A\subseteq \operatorname{int}A$ hence $A=\operatorname{int}A$.

$\Leftarrow:$ Let $A\subseteq \operatorname{int}A$. Let $x\in A$, by assumption there is a neighborhood of $x$ which also lies in $\operatorname{int}{A}$. Union all such neighborhoods. By definition, neighborhoods are open sets and thus $A$, as a union of open sets is also open.
$\blacksquare$

Would this be a good reasoning or am i making it too complicated?

Also one corollary of this should be that

> **Corollary**: $\operatorname{int}A$ is the largest (with respect to inclusion) open set contained in $A$.

*Proof.* If $X\subseteq A$ is open, then by the same reasoning $X\subseteq \operatorname{int}A$ (because any neighborhood of $x\in X$ is also a neighborhood in $A$ thus lies in $\operatorname{int}A$). Union of all such neighborhoods (thus open sets) lying in $A$ forms $\operatorname{int}A$.

But why should union of all open sets in $A$ form precisely $\operatorname{int}A $?

Comment: Note that neighborhoods are not by definition open.

Comment: What's the definition of neighborhood that you are working with?

Comment: It's posted up above. -> Neighborhood of a set $A$ is arbitrary open set containing $A$ <-

Comment: All your reasoning looks correct to me. As for your question " why should union of all open sets in $A$ form precisely int $A$", this follows from the definition of int $A$, and you used this fact in your $\impliedby$ proof.

Comment: This post actually explained a lot to me https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/135872/showing-that-a-set-is-open-in-a-topological-space?rq=1 especially with the union argument.

Comment: Of course it is true that whether or not a set is open depends on the topology. The set of all open sets $is$ the topology.  We often speak of a topological spce $X$ but a topological space is actually a pair $(X,T)$ where  $T$ is some topology on $X$. So when speaking about the space $(X,T)$, the phrase "$A$ is open" means $A\in T$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the proof of the $\Rightarrow$ in the first theorem rigorous. Assume for each $a\in A$ there is a neighborhood $N_a\subseteq A$. Thus for each $a\in A$ is also in $\operatorname{int}{A}$. Set $\mathcal{N}:=\bigcup_{a\in A}N_a\subseteq A$. Now, we wish to show that $A\subseteq \mathcal{N}$. But this is true, because for each $a\in A$ there is a neighborhood $N_a\subseteq \mathcal{N}$ (by assumption), thus $A\subseteq \mathcal{N}$, thus $A=\mathcal{N}$. By definition, all of $N_a$ are open sets and $\mathcal{N}$ is union of open sets which is also by definition open, thus $A$ is open. Q.E.D.